# Создание своих тренировок

Tags: android, java

Всем привет, делаю приложение для тренировок, простенький справочник. Сам в программировании недолго, так что не надо кидаться тапками по пустякам. Вообщем суть вопроса, у меня есть лэйауты(Блоки в которых есть вся инфа о тех или иных упражнениях), так вот, можно как-нибудь сделать так, чтобы при активации , к примеру, "Чек бокса" и при нажатии кнопки "Подтвердить" эти лэйауты отображались на другом "Активити"? Знаю, что можно, так вот, если кто знает пособия или может есть книжки по этой или похожей теме, то очень прошу их кинуть мне. Заранее очень благодарен.

Comment: очень абстрактный вопрос.. почитай startandroid.ru

Comment: ну а если не хочешь читать, есть отличный вариант с видео:)
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzE7HcbvyEiS5ea1rVRbPLQ